# What was in it for Viper?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine

In *The Wolverine*, is the motivation behind Viper's involvement in Yashida's immortality project ever explained? I can only recall her mentioning that Yashida hired her.

Comment: The Wolverine doesn't done justice to many character's development and viper is one of them.

Answer (score 4):

> I can only recall her mentioning that Yashida hired her.

It might not be worth a complete answer since it's just speculation, but I'd consider that motivation enough for her. *Yashida* is extremely rich and goes out of his way to overcome death, so it's likely he paid her quite a good amount for her services. Unlike *Harada*, *Viper* doesn't seem like a person whose loyalty is driven by higher ideals than mere payment.

If she had really just been the doctor she was introduced as, you wouldn't ask for her motivation either (well Ok, you could say doctors have an iherent motivation to heal people, but they usually won't do it for free either).

Comment: I will say the answer is *weak character development*

Comment: @AnkitSharma Well, there are countless examples (in this or a trillion other movies) of mercenaries that were just hired by someone and whose motivation you don't ask for either. A not developing character motivated only by monetary reasons isn't much far from reality at all.

Comment: But i still feel the comic counterpart of viper is more well developed.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Ok, that may be, as I don't have this comparison at hand myself.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Does Viper have a better motive in the comics?

Comment: @coleopterist  She also serve as the leader of HYDRA under the codename Madame Hydra. And she was not mutant in the comics and not even that lame.